# Compact Framework targeting

Tags: .net, compact-framework, windows-ce

If a smart device project is set to target CF 2.0, Windows CE 5.0, should this same application run on Windows Mobile 6 with CF 3.5 installed?

I was able to install it (the CF 2 app), but when running received an error stating that the assemblies could not be loaded and that CF might not be installed.
This has led me to belive that smart device projects wil ONLY work on the framework they target, not any versions lower or greater.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use an App.confiog or MAchine.config file [to set version compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5cd9b2c.aspx) for your application.  [This blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/stevenpr/archive/2004/12/30/344540.aspx) talks about running 1.0 apps under 2.0, but the process is the same.

Answer (score 0):

I have a CF2.0 Project targeted at WinCE5, it runs on WinCE6 CF35 too. Windows Mobile is a lot different in some places. Try to change your target CF35 and Win Mobile and see which warnigs will be thrown.
open the projectfile in a text editor and change `<TargetFrameworkVersion>v3.5</TargetFrameworkVersion>`.
Change the target platform in VisualStudio. Rightclick on the project, -> Change Target..